# Does "ip_forward" need to be enabled for any iptables SNAT/DNAT (postrouting/prerouting) rules?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing, nat

I remember I had to enable `ip_forward` kernel parameter in the past in order to run SNAT/DNAT rules in `iptables` successfully.

Today I was reading this post: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxFRX7UFUIT2GD/How-to-Add-DNS-Filtering-to-Your-NAT-Instance-with-Squid

Per the author of above post, ***You do not have to enable IP Forwarding or add any FORWARD rule***. You may search for the bold text in above article.

and then the author goes on to configure 2 iptables `prerouting (DNAT)` rules.

**Questions:** So, Does this mean that `postrouting/prerouting` (DNAT/SNAT) can work without **`ip_forward`** ? OR am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: In the mentioned aws link he is writing bout changing the port to another port on the same machine, this could be the reason it will work

Answer (score 2):

Quoting

> By default, the IPv4 policy in Linux kernels disables support for IP forwarding. This prevents machines that run Linux from functioning as dedicated edge routers.

I made a test of redirection of the port 80 to a VM with `PREROUTING` without `ip_forward` enabled and it didn't work. When enabling `ip_forward` it success. So as I saw, the `ip_forwarding` option enables is necessary for the `DNAT/SNAT` service.

See more in [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Security_Guide/index.html#sect-Security_Guide-Firewalls-FORWARD_and_NAT_Rules)

Comment: I disagree, you do not need IP forwarding enabled in the kernel to do something that doesn't involve forwarding. I just tested this.